# Should emunah and theology be combined?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Questions in Emunah tend to be about what Jews believe, or the halachos of Jewish Faith. In other religions that sort of thing falls under the topic of theology. Should the tags be made synonymous?

Comment: Also about tags for _emuna_: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1851

Answer (score 2):

Emunah the state of believing in God. Theology is the study of God. These topics can, of course, overlap, but they're by no means identical.